# Node js express Session get expired when change in code

Tags: node.js, express, session

Hi i am doing login application using node js (express framework) and mysql, for this using express-session. my session getting expires soon and also when there is change in code. I am using nodmon for automatic server response. I have attached my code here,

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
  secret: 'page builder',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {secure: false, expires: new Date(Date.now() + 
  config.sessionTime)}
}));
```

setting session after user login:

```
app.post('/loginuser', function (req, res){
var datajsonEle = req.body;
con.query('SELECT * FROM users where userId=?', datajsonEle.userID, function (error, results, fields){
    if (error){
        throw error;
    }else {
        if(results.length > 0){
            if(results[0].password === datajsonEle.userPassword){
                sess = req.session;
                sess.userInfo = results[0];
                req.session.save();
                res.end("success");
            }else {
                res.end("password");
            }
        }else {
            res.end("userId");
        }
        // res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    }
});
});
```

When redirect to home.

```
var sess;
app.get('/', function (req, res, next){
sess = req.session;
console.log(sess);
if(sess.userInfo !== undefined){
    console.log(sess.userInfo.initStage);
    if(sess.userInfo.initStage === 0){
        res.render('index', { title: sess.userInfo });
    }else {
        res.redirect('/home');
    }
}else {
    res.redirect('/login'); 
}
});
```

For every time when i reload after 5 min or changed my code and reload session getting empty. Please help me i am new to node js

Comment: The session is destroyed every time the server restarts. When you make changes in code the code needs to be re compiled therefore loss of session

Comment: Its right, but the session destroyed after 5 min also.

Answer (score 0):

The default store for `express-session` is the MemoryStore, which disappears when express restarts!

You need to use the `store` variable when initializing `express-session` to set the initialized store. The package [has a list of options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores). Most require a persistent database somewhere (MongoDB, redis, memcache), but there is [session-file-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store) if you're just trying things out locally.